# C++ Missing child member from parent pointer?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have this portion of code:

```cpp
enum PROPERTY_TYPE
{
    TYPE_BOOLEAN,
    TYPE_INTEGER,
    TYPE_UNSIGNED,
    TYPE_FLOAT,
    TYPE_STRING
};
struct Property
{
    Property(PROPERTY_TYPE type) : _Type(type) {  }
    PROPERTY_TYPE       _Type;
};
struct Property_Bool : Property
{
    Property_Bool(bool value = false) : Property(TYPE_BOOLEAN), _Value(value) {  }
    bool                _Value;
};
struct Property_Integer : Property
{
    Property_Integer(int value = 0) : Property(TYPE_INTEGER), _Value(value) {  }
    int                 _Value;
};
struct Property_Unsigned : Property
{
    Property_Unsigned(unsigned int value = 0) : Property(TYPE_UNSIGNED), _Value(value) {  }
    unsigned int        _Value;
};
struct Property_Float : Property
{
    Property_Float(float value = 0.0f) : Property(TYPE_FLOAT), _Value(value) {  }
    float               _Value;
};
struct Property_String : Property
{
    Property_String(std::string value = "") : Property(TYPE_STRING), _Value(value) {  }
    std::string         _Value;
};
```

And when I tried this:

```
Property* p1 = new Property_Bool(false);
printf("%d", p1->_Value);
```

I get:

```
error: 'struct Property' has no member named '_Value'
```

I'm actually trying to use them in a map defined as:

```
std::map< std::string, Property* >          _Properties;
```

Comment: The error is exacly what it says. The base class doesn't have the member you desire.

Comment: So, it doesn't work even if I placed the a derived class instance in the base class pointer? And the pointer points to a derived class instead. Because the things I've read and viewed brought be to the conclusion that this is supposed to work!

Comment: It's not supposed to work. If you have a `Property*` then it's not known until runtime whether it actually points to an object of type `Property` or some derived class. In this case since you are sure that the pointer points to a `Property_Bool`, you can use `static_cast<Property_Bool*>(p1)->_Value`. In general, when you're not sure, you can use a `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Casting in such situation is a design smell. If you know that the property should be `Property_Bool` then pass it as such. If you don't, you have to use facilities offered by polymorphism, such as virtual functions, e.g. `getValue()`. In your instance it's more complicated, since you're retutning not only numbers, but strings as well. What you're after is to have a common container for different basic types. You might want to look at `boost::any`.

Comment: boost is what I'm running away from in the first place!